What animals would sapient cats domesticate?
So I'm working on a project, Catworld (placeholder name), which focuses on a world where humans as we know them don't exist, and sapient cats essentially replace them. The cats in question are regular cats (except for the fact that they're sapient and have technology and stuff), so yeah, no furries, no catgirls, nothing of that sort.
Another thing I would like to note is that the world's animals are pretty much the same as Earth animals, save for a few mythical creatures here or there.
So I have a question: what kinds of animals would cats domesticate, given the chance to do so? What I initially had in mind, was goats and sheep for livestock, dogs for protection, owls for getting rid of pests, and frogs and lizards as cute little pets. But I would also like to hear your ideas.
(the cats I’m referring to are domestic cats)

Small cats such as Felis catus, or big cats such as Panthera leo?

Or 1960's hippie?

@AlexP Domestic cat.

Domestic cats are about six to eight times smaller than wolves. For comparison, humans are only about two to three times smaller than lions, and we would never even think about domesticating lions. (And, even more importantly, cats don't have a compatible social structure into which the wolves could assimilate. The compatibility of social structures was essential for humans and wolves to become partners.)

I'm thinking this is a very opinion based question.

Are you also editing the domestic cats normal social structure to a more modern human one to go along with their more human like intelligence? .. because as @AlexP has hinted in his comment them having a compatible social structure to slot domesticated partner species into may be desirable for verisimilitude.

My Cat(s) would like to make the argument: What makes you think that Domestic Cats haven't already domesticated other species? Now if you'll excuse me, the food bowl is not at the satisfactory levels of fullnes...

@Pelinore That’s a good question. I’ll have to think about that one. Initially I assumed the cats would have human social structures, but to be honest it would be pretty interesting if it was different than that.

Voting to close: this is a brainstorm question to produce a list where just about any creature could be argued. It’s not directly answerable.

there are several forms of domestication. There's co-habitation like dogs, farming as food animals, training as tools (horses), and whatever you call it when you keep something in a cage (like fish or gerbils). Can you be more specific?

VTC:Opinion-Based. This isn't a worldbuilding quesiton. Worldbuilding rules must be true regardless any story circumstance. Humanity has tried to domesticate almost everything that can be domesticated (not all creatures can). So what's stopping your cats from doing the same? What critter makes the most sense? Whatever's necessary for your story - because it's irrelevant to the world at large.

One more thing, please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]. Stack Exchange doesn't accept every question and it's important to understand the limits. This question violates the "all answers have equal value" prohibition because without the ability to point to what a sapient species of cats have actually done, it's nothing more than a guess what they would do.

While not an answer to your question, here's a question that can help you decide what you want for an answer.

@TheDemonLord humans are of course the ideal animal for cats to domesticate, but the ultimate test of domestication is who spays and neuters whom.

@gs - given my cats sharp claws and propensity to knead bread on my legs, I am taking this as a sign that's it's not through lack of trying....

This is looking like a duplicate of this question, though it being over 5 years old there might be some newer, better answers.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I see what you did there... ;-)

Here is another question that talks about what makes a species a good candidate for domestication in the general case: What land based animals lend themselves to domestication?

"The cats in question are regular cats" if they don't have thumbs how do they have the technology

Domesticated animals have utility for humans. They fill a variety of roles:

Muscle power in the case of beasts of burden.
Transportation (also in the case of beasts of burden)
Meat and fat
Producers of some other edible substance, like milk or eggs.
Clothing (leather, wool, etc)
Companionship, like, well... domesticated cats.
Security (think: guard dogs)

So, what utility would animals have for sapient domesticated cats? Think of their shortcomings:

They are small relative to many animals.
They sleep a lot.
They still need to eat.

And why do they still need to hunt?



If we are being cynical, you could eliminate companionship, but all of the other things domesticated animals provide should be considered.
So, I can't give you a list of animals; just a challenge. What about your world, the cats' culture would cause them to spend time and energy maintaining another species? It will be easier to think about if you make the pets relevant to some plot point or to enhance the scenery. When in doubt, go for something familiar to the animals consuming your story: humans. Often times stories with sapient species offer a reflection of our own lives and challenges. Use that to make something up and weave it into the storyline.

Domestication results from three processes- first is capture. We captured cows and they accepted being kept in enclosures and protection, in exchange for freedom.
Catworld: Meatmice, bred to generate huge steaks. Hamsters and goldfish.
The other are hunting - we went symbiotic with dogs because they integrate into our hunting and/or protection structure, and they have the ability to integrate into packs. They had abilities we humans had not.
Catworld: Imagine one of those rats with a brain disease, seeking the company of cats. Now imagine it turning on other rats/mice, flushing them out. That could be a hunting companion usefull for a cat. That or a weasel.
Third opportunistic protector, who used the changed landscape to park itself in a comfort zone. Self-domisticated also known as cats.
Catworld: The cat of cats, would hunt for wild domesticated animals, going for the supply storage. Could be a snake, a smaller cat or something similar.

There were four major waves of domestication of animals in human history:

Animals that help to gather food (e.g. dogs)
Animals that create food from resources that are not edible (cattle)
Animals that help with transportation (e.g. horses)
Animals as companions (hamsters)

Trying to extrapolate from that, and taking the size of cats as a very important factor (and ignoring the lack of an opposing thumbs somewhat):

Cats wouldn't gather; they would hunt meat, usually in the form of small rodents. Only a few animals have the capability to help cats in doing so. One possibility is Kestrel falcons. Kestrels can see the urine trails left by  rodents and hover over them, waiting for prey. Sentient cats would be able to see a hovering bird and learn to seek scent trails under them. Cats would start to leave leftover meat for kestrels in places where they want to hunt, which would draw birds to them. This is quite similar to a way we believe the wolves were domesticated. Other good candidates for a similar pathway are the corvids. They have kind of a pack mindset which can be exploited, and young chicks (kidnapped from nests) are much more easily imprinted than falcons.

Rodents are easy to keep, eat things that cats don't and multiply rather readily.

This can be quite wild. I love the idea of a cat warlord riding a chariot drawn by rabbits or a pack of cats hanging from a sheep fleece. But there is a problem mainly in  the fact there is no animal of the right size for cats to act as a mount and having a characteristic of mount animals like donkeys, horses or camels. I doubt rodents can be bred into "smartness" and obedience you need (though guinea pig oxen? maybe?). If you went the sheep route, you lack the herding capability humans had with dogs and the fact that humans are bigger than sheep. This can be amended if cats found a way to control the leading ram - a technique that can be later used for training the sheep as mounts. The other issue is the cats' lack of means to protect the herd.

Cats would keep hamsters as well. Also fish and small birds. Seeing the tiny beast wriggle and pace to and frow is utterly satisfying for every feline.



hamster were not domesticated as companions they were domesticated for animal testing.

Rodents and enslave each other perhaps. Cats would not need domestic animals for the same reason as humans. No need of clothing, leather etc,. Just food.
They don't need dogs to help them hunt or anything else. They'd exterminate them as dangerous predators. They would probably exterminate all land carnivores.

Humans are top predators as well but they did not exterminate all land carnivores. First, they were unable to, now they are seen as valuable and protected.

@alamar we're not carnivores, and we have exterminated most large land carnivores almost everywhere as they mess with our domesticated livestock or do something else we don't like. Or even just made their habitat unliveable for them. Ironically Westerners want to protect the remaining ones in other countries after having exterminated all in the West.

You may expect there to be little big carnivores where sentient cats live, but more places where they don't live (or not as dense) with big carnivores intact.

So, think about why humans domesticated animals. Initially, we only had domesticated animals, such as working animals and livestock. Then, as society developed, and we stopped living day to day, we formed the culture of having pets for companionship or decoration.
Now thinking about cats, we initially domesticated them as a form of pest control. So would cats need pest control? Probably not, since they're carnivores. They're also hunters with a tendency to instinctively go after anything small that moves, so pets are unlikely, depending on how their culture developed.
Would they put in the time and effort it takes to tend to livestock?
Cats sleep for most of the day in order to limit the energy required to sustain themselves. If they sleep, they don't have to hunt. If they don't have to hunt, they don't risk getting hurt, or losing prey. Then they don't have to hunt as much. The cycle continues.
I think cats would probably choose to keep small, harmless creatures as toys.
The rest really depends on what kind of story you want to write. Are the cats following a feline version of our history, or is it wholly unique? If it's just our history, just replace existing domesticated creatures with smaller variants.
